# Firefox "noscript" allow for one site

Tags: firefox, noscript

How can I enable some scripts to run on only one domain? For example I want to allow scripts from `google.com` but only for `mail.google.com`?
I've found out [here](https://superuser.com/questions/587367/noscript-how-to-allow-script-on-one-domain-only), that I can do it using the ABE feature. So I've enable ABE and added the rule :

```
Site .google.com
Accept from .google.com
Deny INCLUSION(OBJ, SUBDOC)
```

(and I've also experimented with that rules syntax: adding an asterisk, adding the SELF keyword etc.)

But it looks that ***nothing*** changes... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The [NoScript ABE forum](http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=18039) discussion has more details; but, try reformatting your rule like this:

```
Site .google.com
Accept INCLUSION from mail.google.com
Deny
```

Google scripts are widely used by web sites and blocking them completely (with `Deny`) can interfere with browsing on many sites. If cookie tracking is the main concern, then replacing `Deny` with `Anonymize` might be get the desired effect with less breakage:

```
Site .google.com .gstatic.com .googleapis.com
Accept INCLUSION from mail.google.com
Anonymize
```

Replacing `Anonymize` with `Sandbox` is another blocking option. [NoScript's log messages](http://noscript.net/abe/users.html) in the JavaScript console (Ctrl+Shift+J) provide lots of good information when writing new rules.

With the rule in place, you can select "Allow all from .google.com" (ditto for .gstatic.com and .googleapis.com) in NoScript's popup menu and then let ABE block the scripts everywhere except for mail.google.com (GMail's domain-name).

Comment: Is it true that ABE is not working as from NoScript version 11.x? In this link https://www.ghacks.net/2017/11/21/noscript-10-webextension-is-out/, it's is mentioned that it's not available in version 10. Would be incredibly helpful to apply per-site rules though! Any alternatives?

Comment: [uBlock Origin, medium mode](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Blocking-mode:-medium-mode) provides a good alternative.
If you're using a Chrome-based browser, be forewarned, however, that Google's [Chrome Extension Manifest v3](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/01/22/chrome-extension-manifest-v3-could-end-ublock-origin-for-chrome/) threatens to [disable uBlock Origin](https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uBlock-issues/issues/338#issuecomment-456134855) and other innovative extensions that use the blocking features of the `webRequest` API.